# Maven properties propagation

Tags: java, maven, web

The workflow is the following:

1. I either get a zip archive with a frontend build or it is downloaded from nexus repository
2. This archive is placed under some of the modules in my project
3. I build my source code and maven properties are being set into some placeholders in UI files and some of them break UI logic in a way

Is there a way to control which properties are being propagated and then correctly set into corresponding placeholders while other properties would be ignored?

P.S. changing UI sources isn't an option, unfortunately

Comment: Profiles, maybe? Although your issue is a bit unclear to me.

Comment: I don't understand point 3. Could you give an example?